# IDLE shell not able to find image for cx_Oracle (Reason: image not found)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-idle, cx-oracle

**Hi - I've successfully installed cx_Oracle on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10 and I am able to query my oracle database through mac terminal using Python 2.7.11 in terminal.**

The only problem is that the IDLE shell application cannot import cx_Oracle and displays the following error:

```
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 12:54:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so, 2): Library not loaded: /ade/b/3071542110/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Below is what I am seeing in my Mac terminal (I can then proceed to successfully query the database):

```
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 12:54:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>>
```

**What am I missing with IDLE that does not allow to import cx_Oracle?**

Comment: Puzzling.  You nicely showed that you are running the same python binary each time.  Did you run IDLE with an icon?  Did you try running it from the terminal command line with `python -m idlelib.idle`?  (This might give additional error messges.) Do you run anything else between the two import attempts?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I did run IDLE with an icon. That icon was pinned to my dock. running the:
`python -m idlelib.idle`
command in mac terminal worked. I ran the command and then did the     `import cx_Oracle`
and I saw that cx_Oracle was successfully imported.

Thanks for your help. I suppose I thought that opening python 2.7.11 with the icon would have allowed me to still `import cx_Oracle`

Comment: @TerryJanReedy if you submit your answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running IDLE from a pinned icon, run it with `python -m idlelib.idle`.  (For 3.x, `.idle` is not needed.)  I don't know why this works better in this case, but I know that running from icons sometimes hides needed info, such as the binary that will be run, the current working directory python will run in, startup arguments, and some error messages.